# BottomNavigation not hiding when keyboard pops for EditText in ScrollView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm new to android development. I'm using latest android studio and trying to develop an android app. I'm using Bottom Navigation to swap among different fragments. I've used ScrollView on the fragment_container in the activity_main.xml file. Each fragment contains an EditText and whenever I tap the EditText to enter something, the keyboard pops up and so does the BottomNavigation on top of keyboard. I can't get the BottomNavigation to hide.
Whenever i enable the ScrollView, the BottomNavigation also comes up with the keyboard. If i remove the SCrollView than it doesn't.
Is there any way to hide it with XML file?
Or it can only be done via code?

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwN9v.png

2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz0DX.png

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your manifest like this way.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

This work for me, Happy Coding

Comment: If i use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", the ScrollView doesnt work at all.

Comment: Add this line in onResume() of your Activity or Fragment.

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);